# Как добавить атрибут checked если value имеет значение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Учусь программировать, но не так все гладко и легко дается.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда value имеет значение, checkbox был активирован, нужно вставить ему атрибут checked.
Написал код, который якобы работает, но если буду обращаться к конкретному элементу. Но у меня задача другая.
Есть родитель, в нем располагается несколько input, input со значением checkbox находится первым, два остальных input со значением text ниже.
Если один из этих полей имеет текс, нужно добавить тогда в checkbox атрибут checked="true".

Не могу пока понять логику обращения к конкретному элементу. Получается только к родителю присвоить.
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```js
$('.info-dop_time').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('#checkbox-dop_time').attr('checked', 'true', !this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
               <label for="button1">
                 <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime" id="checkbox-dop_time">
              </div>
              <div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
               <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
               <input type="text" value="">
               <input type="text" value="текст">
              </div>
```

Comment: `value` *чего* имеет значение?

Comment: Если input не пуст, добавить атрибут чекбоксу чтобы он был активен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на js c возможностью ввода и удаления данных из полей. 
Если данные введены - проставляется checked
Если удалены в обоих полях - убирается.

```js
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('info-dop_time');
    var param = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_show_doptime');
    for (let i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
        var elem1 = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (let z=0;z<elem1.length;z++){
            if (elem1[z].value || elem1[z].innerText){
                param[i].checked = true;
            } else {
                param[i].checked = false;
            }
            elem1[z].oninput = function () {
                var elem1 = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
                param[i].checked = false;
                for (let z1=0;z1<elem1.length;z1++) {
                    if (elem1[z1].value || elem1[z1].innerText) {
                        param[i].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
    <label for="button1">
        <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime" id="checkbox-dop_time">
</div>
<div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
    <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
    <label for="button1">
        <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime" id="checkbox-dop_time">
</div>
<div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
    <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
    <label for="button1">
        <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime" id="checkbox-dop_time">
</div>
<div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
    <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.info-dop_time').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).find('input').val();
  $(this).prev('.checkbox-dop_time').
    find('.btn_show_doptime').prop('checked', value != '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
  <label for="button1">
    <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime">
</div>
<div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
  <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
  <input type="text" value="текст">
</div>
<div class="time__iner checkbox-dop_time">
  <label for="button1">
    <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn_show_doptime" checked>
</div>
<div class="time__iner iner__time info-dop_time">
  <span class="add_h5">Время подготовки:</span>
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```